# Is it possible to defer income for a child's education

Tags: college, job-offer

I have a 16 year old who will be going to college soon.

I received a job offer that I have not accepted yet and it includes an annual bonus.

Before accepting the offer I wanted to find out what my options are for the annual bonus with regard to college education.

Is there anything special that I can do here?  For example, can I leave it at the company until it's needed so that it's not considered when I am evaluated for financial aid?  Are there certain company perks that would help (similar to commuter expense or medical expense account)?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a potential idea considering the short time frame: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/164/how-can-a-529-plan-help-me-save-for-my-childs-college-education

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To break down the question as best I can, you are concerned about end up in a higher tax bracket before a financial aid assessment?

*"... can I leave it at the company until it's needed so that it's not considered when I am evaluated for financial aid?"*

Likely not.  They are expecting to pay it out as payroll.  A small family company might give you that flexibility.  Sometimes large companies allow you defer across a tax year (one bank I worked for allowed a shift from December to January for this exact purpose), but eventually they stopped that as it made a tax accounting nightmare for them.

There may well be perks, as you also ask.  Your company health benefits commonly extend to dependant children.  If they cover dental, drugs, co-payments and the like, that may well be a significant benefit to you and your child.